# get value from concated array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I concat two json array.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var json_from_data = [{acceleration: 15,
              cylinders: 4,
              displacement: 98,
              horsepower: 80,
              id: 90,
              model_year: 72,
              mpg: 28,
              name: "dodge colt (sw)",
              origin: 1,
              weight: 2164},

{acceleration: 14,
cylinders: 8,
displacement: 307,
horsepower: 130,
id: 80,
model_year: 72,
mpg: 13,
name: "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)",
origin: 1,
weight: 4098}],


    json_from_form = [{color: 'displacement', 
              name: "name",
              x: "mpg",
              y: "acceleration"}];
```

This is a function to concat two arrays

```
$.concat||$.extend({concat:function(b,c){var a=[];for(x in arguments)a=a.concat(arguments[x]);return a}});
var new_data = $.concat(json_from_data, json_from_form);
```

Now I want to have value  from `new_data` using key

```
console.log(new_data);
console.log(new_data[2].color);
console.log("id", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.id}));
console.log("mpg", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.mpg}));
console.log("color", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.color}));
```

If I do this I am receiving a solution with undefined.

```
id [90, 80, undefined] 
mpg [28, 13, undefined] 
color [undefined, undefined, "displacement"]
```

How to avoid undefined value, if I want to have value from concated array?

I want to have an solution like

```
id [90, 80] 
mpg [28, 13] 
color ["displacement"]
```

Here is my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/toshkaexe/Q5vZL/)

Answer (score 0):

Just write a filter function, like this:

```
function test(arr) {

    return arr.filter(function(ele) {

        return ele !== undefined;
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j89aB/

Comment: No. I want after 

`console.log("id", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.id}));
console.log("mpg", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.mpg}));
console.log("color", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.color}));`

nothing doing

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to come from your `map()` function, rather than your array concatenation. It appears your `map()` function returns `undefined`, which are then included into the result-array you see.

Most standard way would be to `filter()` the `map` result, to exclude undefined values.

```
var isDefined = function(v) {return v !== undefined;}
console.log("id", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.id}).filter( isDefined) );
console.log("mpg", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.mpg}).filter( isDefined) );
console.log("color", new_data.map(function(d) { return d.color}).filter( isDefined) );
```

Alternately you could create a "mapValuesOnly()" function, to combine these two behaviours.

```
function mapValuesOnly (arr, func) {
    var results = arr.map( func);
    results = results.filter( 
        function(v) {return v !== undefined;});
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter is one of the solution. But the problem is in your concat/extents code. Let's use lodash(_) to see how it can be done.

Steps to be followed:

1) Find all the unique keys from both the arrays

```
let uniqueKeys = _.uniq([...(_.keys(json_from_data[0])), ...(_.keys(json_from_data[0]))])
```

This will return

> ["acceleration", "cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "id", "model_year", "mpg", "name", "origin", "weight"]

2) Merge both array data

```
let mergedData = [...json_from_data, ...json_from_form]
```

This will return 
[{acceleration: 15, cylinders: 4, displacement: 98, horsepower: 80, id: 90, …}
 {acceleration: 14, cylinders: 8, displacement: 307, horsepower: 130, id: 80, …}
 {color: "displacement", name: "name", x: "mpg", y: "acceleration"}]

3) `let newdata = [];
uniqueKeys.forEach((keyy) => {
      let arr = [];
      mergedData.forEach(item => {
        if (item[keyy]) {
          arr.push(item[keyy]);
        }
      })
      newdata.push({ [keyy]: arr })
    })`

This will return:

> [{"acceleration":[15,14]},{"cylinders":[4,8]},{"displacement":[98,307]},{"horsepower":[80,130]},{"id":[90,80]},{"model_year":[72,72]},{"mpg":[28,13]},{"name":["dodge colt (sw)","chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)","name"]},{"origin":[1,1]},{"weight":[2164,4098]}]

I hope this works!